# Aligned sections for dynamically loaded libraries

Tags: assembly, ld

The GNU assembler supports aligning sections to boundaries. A use of this capability can be seen in this sample program:

```
// test.S
    .section foo,"aw"
    .p2align 20
    .global foo_start
foo_start:
    .ascii "A"

// main.c
#include 
extern char foo_start;
int main(void) {
    printf("%c\n", foo_start); // force libtest.so to be loaded
    printf("%p\n", &foo_start);
}
```

When this program is statically linked, we see that the section is properly aligned:

```
ezyang@javelin:~/Dev/labs/reloc$ gcc test.S main.c -g && ./a.out
A
0x700000
```

However, this does not work when the library is loaded dynamically instead:

```
ezyang@javelin:~/Dev/labs/reloc$ gcc test.S  -shared -o libtest.so -fPIC
ezyang@javelin:~/Dev/labs/reloc$ gcc -Wl,-R`pwd` -L. main.c -ltest -g -O0
-fPIC && ./a.out
/usr/bin/ld: warning: type and size of dynamic symbol `foo_start' are not
defined
A
0x7f012f9e7000
```

Is there a way to make the dynamic linker respect alignment requests bigger than a page? Maybe using big pages?

Comment: Could this be the result of [address space layout randomization](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aslr)?

Comment: Disabling ASLR does not appear to make a difference. But I agree; having to align a library to a large block offset would make ASLR a bit harder.